# Need image to bounce

Tags: css

I want an image to bounce.  I have tried several suggestions from searching stackoverflow, but so far nothing is working. I think something is wrong with my code. Can anyone help? You can see all of the code at the link below.

https://codepen.io/rquery/pen/aXdYem

Thank you!

```
<body>
  <div id="my-grid">
    <section id="pic">
      <div id= "bounce">
      <img alt="Image result for super hero images" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLUGK4r4l2XE9-NOk1VP_EjDDJNEWY6Y7WJvRfgPE8Hyuil7ly">

      </div>
    </section>

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  from,
  20%,
  53%,
  80%,
  to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
```

Comment: you are not calling the animation

Comment: `#bounce img { `[animation: bounce 1s infinite;](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jdWxQW)`}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows insufficient  research efforts.

Comment: I didn't see any examples that provided the above code. Also, when I find so many different examples and they are not working how can I find the correct information and how can I know where the correct information is and what it is? W3Schools should be a good souce, but I wasn't able to use their examples along with many others. I looked for hours. Thank you

Comment: W3Schools is the worst source ... and you will find that code in any example running an animation. can you provide one example you found in the net with an animation and without that code?

Comment: Here is one that I looked at:

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2InFdrCbFQ

Comment: Thanks for info on W3Schools, I haven't been informed of that.  In fact I have heard the opposite.

Comment: https://www.html.am/html-codes/marquees/bouncing-image.cfm

Comment: I looked at the above as well.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined your "bounce" animation, but then you haven't assigned the animation to any element on your page. Add something like this this at the end of your CSS:

```
img { animation: bounce 5s infinite ; }
```

You can learn more about CSS animations like yours at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: Thank you very much Kerri!  I was happy that I was only missing one line of code though.